# XML Схема (XSD) из XML документа. Пространства имён

Tags: xml, xsd

Вожусь уже второй день. Проблема только в том, как определенные атрибуты элементов выделить в отдельное пространство имён. Что бы всё это нормально проходило валидацию

Есть XML вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<main xmlns:ns="myNamespace">
  <institution name="Green_River" ns:type="college">
    <faculty number="27015" ns:specialty="international_elationships">
      <student firstName="Mike" lastName="Junior" age="18" ns:location="NY" />
    </faculty>
  </institution>
</main>
```

Как из этого всего составить схему понять не могу. Пока что получилось так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="unqualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ns="myNamespace"
    targetNamespace="myNamespace"
>
  <xs:element name="main">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="institution" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="faculty" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="student" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="firstName" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="lastName" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="age" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                        <xs:attribute ref="ns:location"/>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                 </xs:sequence>
                 <xs:attribute name="number" type="xs:positiveInteger" use="required"/>
                  <xs:attribute ref="ns:specialty" use="required"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="ns:type"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

      <xs:attribute name="location" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:attribute name="specialty" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sсhema>
```

При такой схеме валидатор (VS) требует, чтобы все теги и элементы были отнесены к пространству ns. Подскажите в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фокус в том, что настройка `elementFormDefault="unqualified"` не применяется к элементам которые объявлены в самой схеме, неквалифицированными могут быть только вложенные элементы внутри complexType.

Вам надо создать две схемы. Одна будет без целевого пространства имен и будет описывать корневой тэг. Вторая будет описывать атрибуты требующие указания пространства имен:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns="myNamespace" targetNamespace="myNamespace">
  <xs:attribute name="location" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="specialty" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns="myNamespace">
  <xs:import namespace="myNamespace" schemaLocation="..." />

  <xs:element name="main">
    <xs:complexType>
      <!-- ... -->
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

В самом документе можно оставить подсказку для редакторов (например, для той же студии) о местоположении схемы:

```
<ns:main xmlns:ns="myNamespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="...">
```